# izpack how to replace backslash "\" with slash "/" or with "\\" in windows directory location with space

Tags: izpack, izpanel

I am using izpack installer to install the application which I developed in Windows.
My application root-folder will have space in it.
There is a property with folder location in configuration .properties file.

```
PluginFolder=${plugin.dir}
```

For example my sample windows-directory location is "C:\My Application Folder\Plugins Folder"

Which required to replace with actual folder-path after installation as follows, because java can not read property in file with only "\" in folder-path.

```
PluginFolder=C:\\My Application Folder\\Plugins Folder

or 

PluginFolder=C:/My Application Folder/Plugins Folder
```

Any one of the above will work fine with my application.

In izpack installer Folder location reads using

```
<panel ...>
...
   <field type="dir" align="left" variable="plugin.dir">
      <spec txt="Plugin Directory :" size="25" set="${plugin.default.dir}" />
   </field>
....
</panel>
```

And properties in configuration file is set using

```
<parsable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/config/myapp.properties" type="javaprop">
   <os family="windows" />
</parsable>
```

But use of type="javaprop" in izpack installer is appending "\" with SPACE present in folder path. That I do not required as my application is not able to read it.

```
PluginFolder=C:\\My\ Application\ Folder\\Plugins\ Folder
```

Use of type="java" works fine if there is no space in folder-path and replace all the "\" with "\". But with space in folder-path, which is very likely in Windows and also required for my application it is not working.

Actually I do not want "SPACE" in folder-path to be replaced by "\SPACE".

Guys please help me to resolve this issue in izpack installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work around this behavior e.g. by using dynamic variables with filtering:

```
<dynamicvariables>
  <variable name="plugin.dir.parsed" value="${plugin.dir}">
    <filters>
      <regex regexp="[/\\]+" replace="/" global="true" />
    </filters>
  </variable>
</dynamicvariables>
```